# Pattern Match and replace numbers in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string as given below

```
channel->0->item->0->guid->0
```

Numbers in this string can vary from 0 to any number

I Want to replace all **->N** into **[N]**

**Expected Result:**  `channel[0]->item[0]->guid[0]`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just capture the number and back-reference it later in the replacement part.

```
preg_replace('~->(\d+)~', '[\1]', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW8kZ0/7)

```
$str = "channel->0->item->0->guid->0";
echo preg_replace('~->(\d+)~', '[\1]', $str);
```

Output:

```
channel[0]->item[0]->guid[0]
```

**Update:**

Do a double-replacement in-order to remove the last `N` after the first replace.

```
$str = "channel->0->item->0->guid->0";
$str = preg_replace('~->(\d+)(?!$)~', '[\1]', $str);
echo preg_replace('~->\d+$~', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
channel[0]->item[0]->guid
```

Comment: I need some modification in this function. Can you help me Please?

Current Result: channel[0]->item[0]->guid[0]
Expected Result: channel[0]->item[0]->guid

How can i remove every last [N]